# How can I call service in subscription but not wait for service to finish before it updates

Tags: typescript, observable, angular5

So I am subscribed to an observable within our store, when it is populated with data, I update rows on a grid.  There is data that I'm going to use to call another service, to update another part of the grid asynchronously.  I'm noticing that is is waiting for the service call within the subscription to finish before it updates the rows.  Is there something I am missing or is there another way I can leverage this subscription to do what I want? Why does it wait for the entire subscription to finish before pushing its results?

```
this.subscription = this.store.pipe(select(s => s.person.friends)).subscribe(
  friends=> {
    if (friends.length !== 0) {
      this.filteredResults = [...friends];

      this.results = friends;
      // logic to get data from friends to make another call
      // the initial update waits until this is complete to update, but i
      // want it to update instantly, then go fetch this extra data
      this.getFriendData(example);

    }
  }
);
```

Comment: You're probably subscribing to the wrong data. Can't tell for sure because you're not specific in what you want populated.

Comment: Please, be more precise. What is the other method call you described? What data do you need for this second call? When do you expect to have it from which source?